# Updating value of xml tag through script

Tags: xml, bash, xmlstarlet

I need to update the value of following xml tag through shell script.

```
<sample>4</sample>
```

I have tried with below, but it doesnt work..

```
sed -i '' 's/\(<[^"]*"sample">\)\([^<]*\)\(<[^>]*\)/\1"$sampleVal"\3/g' $CONFIG_FILE
```

Any idea what is missing?

**Update with complete xml nodes:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
     <Server>
     <userInput>
            <sample>0</sample>
            <A>
            <a1>9999</a1>
            <a2>11111</a2>
           </A>
           <B>
            <b1>10389</b1>
            <b2>8000</b2>
           </B>

         <C>10500</C>
         </userInput>
      </Server>
```

**Update with namespace:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
     <Server xmlns="http://a/b/c/sample.com">
     <userInput>
            <sample>0</sample>
            <A>
            <a1>9999</a1>
            <a2>11111</a2>
           </A>
           <B>
            <b1>10389</b1>
            <b2>8000</b2>
           </B>

         <C>10500</C>
         </userInput>
      </Server>
```

Comment: Do not edit `XML` with text processing tools. A slightest change in `XML` formatting will screw all  the text processing logic adopted. Use an appropriate `XML` parsing tool like [`xmlstarlet`](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Updated with all the elements of <userInput>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With xmlstarlet:

```
xmlstarlet ed -u '/Server/userInput/sample/text()' -v "100" file.xml
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Server>
  <userInput>
    <sample>100</sample>
    <A>
      <a1>9999</a1>
      <a2>11111</a2>
    </A>
    <B>
      <b1>10389</b1>
      <b2>8000</b2>
    </B>
    <C>10500</C>
  </userInput>
</Server>
```

If you want to edit your file "in place" add option `-L`:

```
xmlstarlet ed -L -u '/Server/userInput/sample/text()' -v "100" file.xml
```

If you want to omit XML declaration (`<?xml ...?>`) add option `-O`:

```
xmlstarlet ed -O -u '/Server/userInput/sample/text()' -v "100" file.xml
```

Output:

```
<Server>
  <userInput>
    <sample>100</sample>
    <A>
      <a1>9999</a1>
      <a2>11111</a2>
    </A>
    <B>
      <b1>10389</b1>
      <b2>8000</b2>
    </B>
    <C>10500</C>
  </userInput>
</Server>
```

Comment: `++` for using the right tool for the job

Comment: Thanks Cyrus. If I have a namespace added to <Server> (<Server xmlns="a/b/c"> ) Should this be included in xmlstarlet command?

Comment: Yes: `xmlstarlet ed -N x="http://a/b/c/sample.com" -u '/x:Server/x:userInput/x:sample/text()' -v "100" file.xml`